# Related Record List in Community Cloud

Tags: lightning-community, partner-communities, experience-cloud, community-cloud

I would like to add the Related Record List to the community porta, but I received the error according to the attached image. I have tried to add {!AccountId} and {!Account.Id} into Parent Record ID and Service_Purchased__c, Service_Purchased__r, and Service Purchased into Related List Name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the right one is `{!CurrentUser.accountId}`

Comment: Hi @Damecek , I have tried to put {!CurrentUser.AccountId} according to your suggestion, but I still get the same error.

Comment: ah, ok, and what about `{!recordId}`

Comment: @Damecek after I have tried {!recordId}, I receive:
Unfortunately, the related list you're trying to view isn't in the layout. Please get in touch with your administrator.

Answer (score 0):

{!CurrentUser.accountId} is the correct format for the Parent Record ID when you want to display related records for the portal user's Account.

For related records of a custom object, you need to append '__r' to the label for the related list (which can be found by looking at the details of the lookup field on the related object).

Also, the related list that you are referring to needs to be displayed on the Page Layout (ie Classic page layout) for the page layout that is assigned to the profile used for Community users.

Answer (score 0):

Use {!recordId} for the Parent Record. The Related List name is from the url on the full view of the Related List.  Go in Lightning and click on an example of the full list view of your related list and you will see the name at the end of the url.  It will probably be ServicePurchased in your case.
You can see in my example that when I was looking for Files related list on Quotes, I had to use AttachedContentDocuments as my Related List Name.

[image]